# Why is rvalue incrementing in C++ illegal?

Tags: c++, increment, rvalue

What is the problem of rvalue incrementing? Is there any convincing answer, why this code should be illegal in C++:

```
int f(int x) {return x + 1;}
int main() {
  std::cout << ++f(2) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you prefer it always be allowed, even in the cases where it is an obvious error?

Comment: Because rvalues, in a way, doesn't really *exist*, they are just temporary. And the `++` operator (both prefix and suffix) needs to write the incremeneted result somewhere, and that can't be done on something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Because the C++ specification (e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) forbids it. I am not sure it makes sense to understand the motivation of every every feature in the language. Intuitively you can increment only a "location", which `f(2)` is not (it is just an `int`, and you cannot increment 3, e.g. `++3` makes no sense)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude rvalues are expressions; expressions exist.  Values and temporary objects exist too.  You can do `++f(2)` if `f` has class type so that is not really a convincing explanation

Comment: @M.M: in the question, `f` is *defined* as `int f(int x) {return x + 1;}` so don't have a class type

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I was responding to someprogrammerdude's comment (which logic is not specific to this particular `f`)

Answer (score 3):

We can conject about its absurdity or otherwise until the cows come home, but the short answer is really that you can't do this since nobody has convinced the standards committee that it could be useful. Perhaps you could?

In some instances, such has code exploiting overloaded operators (e.g. Boost Spirit), it could indeed be useful.

One argument against its introduction would be compiler complexity.

As a final argument in your favour, note that

```
int n = 0; ++++n;
```

is valid C++, but **not** valid C, as in the latter case `++n` is not an lvalue. What you are proposing is, in a sense, along that evolutionary path insofar that C++ evolved from C.

Comment: Me upvotes for the first paragraph. But the last one isn't too convincing. C++ compilers are already raging behemoths set on eating our cats. This won't make them much worse.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You mean the ++second paragraph?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Oops I've invalidated your comment yet again ;-)

Comment: @StoryTeller: Might keep them away from suspected voting rings...

Comment: I will say one thing about the likelihood of convincing the committee. Any such discussion will likely go as follows: *OP*: "We can reword to allow `++f(2)`". *Committee*: "Why on earth can't you get by with `f(2) + 1`? Declined. Next issue".

Comment: @StoryTeller: Next issue: User defined literals. Yeah, let's do them. Next issue: Modules. Nah.

Answer (score 2):

According to [cpp standard reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) for increment operators:

> The operand expr of a built-in prefix increment or decrement operator must be a modifiable (non-const) lvalue of non-boolean arithmetic type or pointer to complete object type. For non-boolean operands, the expression ++x is exactly equivalent to x += 1, and the expression --x is exactly equivalent to x -= 1, that is, the prefix increment or decrement is an lvalue expression that identifies the modified operand.

From which, `++f(2)` translates to `f(2) = f(2) + 1`, but there's no LHS to store the result of the RHS. `lvalues` are needed for that.